# Truncate text length in drop down

Tags: javascript, css, selectize.js

There are some values in the dropdown which has bigger text length. `selectize.js` automatically changes height of the dropdown in that case and wrap text which makes dropdown height not fixed. I want to truncate text length if it overflows width of dropdown.

**Currently** it looks like this (height of the dropdown automatically expands in this case)
[image: Text Length dropdown]

**Desired**

[image: Dessired]

**HTML**

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    
    <select multiple class="form-control select-key" id="sel2" name="key-list[]">
      <option>SBI Cap</option>
      <option>PGIM MidCap</option>
      <option>Axis SmallCap</option>
      <option>Kotak Technology</option>
      <option>SBI Technology Value Retirement Direct Fund</option>
    </select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
   $("#sel2").selectize({
    onDropdownOpen: function($dropdown) {
        if (!this.lastQuery.length) {
        this.close(); 
        this.settings.openOnFocus = false;
      }
   },   
   onItemAdd: function() {
    this.close();
   },
   onType : function (str) {
        if (str === "") {
            this.close();
        }
   }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.form-control {
 width: 300px !important;
}

.selectize-dropdown {
  width: auto !important;
}

.selectize-dropdown [data-selectable], .selectize-dropdown .optgroup-header {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```